# Is there a performance benefit to using d3's format over react?

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I'm following a tutorial for D3 and React. I followed instructions to render a few text elements but since I'm more experienced in React I was wondering if there would be some performance penalty for not using regular D3 syntax if I'm building a less contrived example like a proper chart.

Here's their example

```
export const Text = ({ data }) => {
  const container = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data && container.current) {
      const svg = select(container.current);

      // Bind D3 data
      const update = svg.append("g").selectAll("text").data(data);

      // Enter new D3 elements
      update
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .attr("x", (d, i) => i * 25)
        .attr("y", 40)
        .style("font-size", 24)
        .text((d) => d);

      // Update existing D3 elements
      update.attr("x", (d, i) => i * 40).text((d) => d);

      // Remove old D3 elements
      update.exit().remove();
    }
  }, [data, container.current]);
  return (
    <svg className="d3-component" width={400} height={200} ref={container} />
  );
};
```

Here's my version:

```
export const Text = ({ data}: IProps) => {
  return (
    <svg className="d3-component" width={400} height={200}>
      {data?.map((datum, i) => (
        <text x={i * 25} y={40} style={{ fontSize: 24 }}>
          {datum}
        </text>
      ))}
    </svg>
  );
};
```

Comment: D3 has so many years, that React didn't event exist back then. So they hav a lot of functionality that you might not need. Feel free to use the tool you are more used to for a specific purpose.

Answer (score 0):

There is one performance benefit that's worth mentioning:

When `data` changes, in React, `data.length` text elements will be removed and then added to the DOM. If `data.length` becomes large, that can be computationally expensive.

Other than that, D3 can use scoped functions to change the output. For example, `.attr('height', d => y(d)).attr('y', height - y(d))` to give a bar chart height or `svg.append('g').call(xAxis)` to draw an axis.

If you really want to use React for more than text, you'll need to either pre-compute these values, or make the functions and variables available to be used by the renderer. If you *don't* want to use React for more than text, then it depends.

If you're adding labels to already drawn bars in a bar chart or points in a line chart, just use D3, because it's easier to handle the lifecycle of these labels directly together with the points that they represent.

Now, if you're adding stand-alone components that don't change much and might use their own data objects (like legends, titles, or text annotations), then there should be no downside to using React over D3.